# Run 'cmake --help' for more information

Tags: cmake

I failed to compile the below software:

```
git clone https://github.com/bioinfologics/satsuma2.git
cd satsuma2
cmake
Usage

  cmake [options] <path-to-source>
  cmake [options] <path-to-existing-build>

Specify a source directory to (re-)generate a build system for it in the
current working directory.  Specify an existing build directory to
re-generate its build system.

Run 'cmake --help' for more information.
```

What did I miss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the `<path-to-source>` - either

```
cmake .
```

or (often recommended - it keeps the toplevel directory clean)

```
mkdir build && cd build
cmake ..
```